# send subscription payment using paypal app to new merchant account not old one

Tags: php, api, paypal

I've implemented the paypal recurring payment with grant permissions by using this paypal grant api `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webscr&cmd='.'_grant-permission&request_token='.$token`  and i've added my classic app id `(APP-80W284485P519543T)` with below merchant credentials.

```
API username:-------,
API Passowrd: ------,
API signature: ------,
```

The above one is working perfect, users can grant permissions for paypal api calls on behalf of the paypal account holder. Here what i wants to know is , everytime when i make recurring payment the amount will be transfered to the merchant account specified in the API credentials. But here how we can *send subscription payment using paypal app* to new merchant account not old one ? I've used this github source for my development [link here](https://github.com/paypal/permissions-sdk-php/tree/namespace-php5.3)

Answer (score 0):

You can't for a subscription. A subscription is tied to the merchant account. To move a subscription you would have to cancel the old subscription and have the user go through the signup process with the new account.